# How can I remove unnecessary whitespace from Java source?

Tags: java, obfuscation

I've seen jquery.min.js and some CSS files with all unnecessary whitespace removed from them. Is there a tool available to do same with Java source for obfuscation purposes?

Comment: Unless you are for some reason sending Java source over networks, this should not be done, due to readability problems.

Comment: This is a JavaScript question, not a Java question, right?

Comment: The way you do this in Java is to compile your code.

Comment: I mean, I don't wanna use space in java file script. not javascript.

Comment: I guess he just wants to accomplish the same thing with a Java file as what can be done with javascripts. So I do think it is a Java question...

Comment: There is no such thing as a `java file script`

Comment: But, why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to remove all the spaces?  This has no impact on performance, download times, execution, loading times, but it does make the code almost unreadable (but not actually unreadable if that is what you want)

Comment: yeah, I wanna unreadable @PeterLawrey

Comment: So you want to obfuscate the code.

Comment: I mean, I have to do unreadable java file. what can I do?

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about Java, the compiled language, and not JavaScript, the language used in web pages?

Comment: The tag is switching from `[java]` to `[javascript]` and back again at least once per second :-)

Comment: @ArnoHlaMoe Is there any reason you can't compile the code and provide `.class` files?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I can understand that. It seems like some more editors were confused as well ;-)

Comment: BTW If you remove the spaces from javascript you can easily add them back in with a JS editor's auto-format function.

Comment: @ArnoHlaMoe: For both Java and JavaScript you can easily and programmatically re-insert spaces and new lines to make the code readable again. People remove space and line breaks from JS files so that they need to transfer fewer bytes to send the data to the clients' browser. It won't work for obfuscation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> yeah, I wanna unreadable

You shouldn't need to provide the original source, you would compile it to byte code as this can be run on any Java platform.

The byte code for compiled code is already difficult to read but it can be decompiled.  You can make it difficult to decompile with a byte code obfuscator.

There are several (commercial and free)

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+obfuscator

This changes the byte in ways that the JVM can read but is not easily read as the original Java or produce compileable code. e.g. turn fields names into numbers etc.

BTW: You can always reverse engineer the code, but you can make it harder to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best way to make your java code unreadable: do not publish your java code.

If you must publish your java code, do not obfuscate it.

There are exactly zero good reasons to obfuscate your java code.